# Less problems vs. fewer problems

Tags: vocabulary

*This attitude will help ensure your students have **less problems** online.*

The sentence above is taken from an online test provided by the University of New South Wales.

I am sure that *less* is not the comparative degree of *little* meaning *minor* here. So *less* must be a determiner here.

In my opinion, *fewer problems* is correct and *less problems* is not because *less* is used with uncountable nouns. I know that in everyday speech *less problems* can possibly be. But how appropriate is this casualism (if I can put it like this) in a test?

Comment: You are correct. The online test is ungrammatical. *Less* is use for uncountable nouns and *fewer* is used for countable nouns. If you can count the number of problems (as you can) then *fewer* should be used.

Comment: @user3169 Even with the interpretation of "severe," the sentence itself would still be ungrammatical. Not because of the use of *less* but because of the plural *problems*. If talking about severity, a correct sentence would be: *This attitude will help insure your students have less of a problem online.* (If the sentence *actually* included the word "severe," which it doesn't, then you're right. If we knew it wasn't a mistake, it would be interpreted, or parsed, as ***less severe*** *problems*.)

Answer (score 2):

Well, in short, I absolutely agree with you. I try not to be prescriptive. Really, I do. But if I read this on a professional website, and most especially on the website for a university, my opinion would be tarnished.